# Sort nested lists in r

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have several lists with N objects each (like `unsorted$b` below) and a data frame with N rows (`unsorted$a` below). All of these are in a single list (`unsorted`). I wish to sort the data frame, while re-arranging every nested list to preserve the general order. For example:

```
> unsorted <- list(a=data.frame(age=c(30,10,20), name=c("ann","bob","carl")), b=list("3x10","1x10","2x10"))
> unsorted
$a
  age name
1  30  ann
2  10  bob
3  20 carl

$b
$b[[1]]
[1] "3x10"

$b[[2]]
[1] "1x10"

$b[[3]]
[1] "2x10"
```

I wish to sort by age

```
ord <- order(unsorted$a$age)
```

and this does the trick:

```
sorted <- list(a=unsorted$a[ord,], b=unsorted$b[ord])
> sorted
$a
  age name
2  10  bob
3  20 carl
1  30  ann

$b
$b[[1]]
[1] "1x10"

$b[[2]]
[1] "2x10"

$b[[3]]
[1] "3x10"
```

Can this be done with apply or one of its incarnations?

**-- EDIT --**

The parent list in my real case has a large number of sublists. All sublists contain N objects, but these objects have variable structures.

Comment: See my edits. Next time try referencing your variable names in your text as well as your code. Your first paragraph would have immediately made sense to me if it had said "I have several lists with N objects each (like `unsorted$b` below) and a data frame with N rows (`unsorted$a` below). All of these are in a single list (`unsorted`)...

Comment: It's clear to me now, of course, but at the first read I thought you meant *each* of your lists had it's own data.frame, but not having to guess which lists in your example you meant by "All this is grouped in a list of data frame and nested lists" would have set me straight more quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your data structure correctly, you have a big list of these sublists, something like this:

```
list_of_lists = list(unsorted, unsorted)
```

You only give one example sublist in your question, so I'm assuming that

- you do have a big list like this
- there is 1 level of nesting, that is, your sublists don't possibly contain more sublists that need sorting, and
- all your sublists have exactly 1 data frame, and it has a column called "age" that determines the ordering.

Write function that does the sorting:

```
sort_list <- function(x) {
    df.index <- which(sapply(x, is.data.frame))
    stopifnot(length(df.index) == 1)
    ord <- order(x[[df.index]]$age)
    lapply(x, FUN = function(y) {
        if (is.data.frame(y)) return(y[ord, ])
        return(y[ord])
    }
    )
}
```

Then `lapply` it to your list of lists:

```
lapply(list_of_lists, sort_list)
```

#### Edit:

Now you've clarified your data structure, I think the thing to do is get the order first, then `lapply` the ordering to everything.

```
# Using your code to get the order:
ord <- order(unsorted$a$age)

lapply(unsorted, function(x, ord) {
      if (is.data.frame(x)) return(x[ord,])
      return(x[ord])
    },
    ord = ord
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. The big list has the data frame and a large number of N-length lists, all of which need to be re-ordered internally. My example simplifies by considering just one of such sublists.

Comment: Applying @Gregor's solution to my case (described in last comment) returns empty sublists. Something needs to be tweaked in the code

Comment: Oh, it sounded like each sublist had a data frame. So it sounds like your example isn't one sublist, but rather a small example of the big list. (That would mean it's a much better example as it stands.) It's also a lot easier, I'll edit later today when I have some time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
lapply(unsorted, function(x) {
    if(is.vector(x)) x[order(unlist(x))] else x[order(x$age),]
})

$a
  age name
2  10  bob
3  20 carl
1  30  ann

$b
$b[[1]]
[1] "1x10"

$b[[2]]
[1] "2x10"

$b[[3]]
[1] "3x10"
```

Comment: Makes even more assumptions that my answer, but much much cleaner (+1).

Comment: Thanks.  It would be lengthy to try to generalize this for all possible data structures.

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven. As I commented above, my big list includes the data frame and a large number of N-length lists (of objects with variable structure). All sublists need re-ordering with the same criterion as the data frame.